# XML Serialazer C# Silverlight

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight-4.0

For some reason i ca´t use this class (XmlSerialazer) on my application on C# silverlight,they jus´t don´t get recognized.
I am calling this librarys on my application

using System.Xml;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
I am pretty sure that all needed library is there, but still the problem why i can´t use this class?
I have to install some ohter library?Or re-install Visual Studio? Or maybe look for another way to get the data on the xml file, if yes How?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Looking [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(VS.95).aspx), you need a reference to `System.Xml.Serialization.dll` - you mention a `using` directive, but it isn't clear whether you have a *reference*. Try adding that if missing.